Building nodemcu (lua) esp32-dev firmware with u8g2 support does not include requested display driver
nodemcu esp32-dev branch cloned to raspberry pi 5. Firmware built with basic modules seems fine, bin files are produced and flashed to espressif esp32-wroom-32 (also generic 32E, dev kit 1,...) using esptool. However adding u8g2 for i2c using make menuconfig and then make results in a missing u8g2.ssd1306_i2c_128x64_noname. Of note, the 3 fonts selected are present, e.g. u8g2.font_6x10_tf.
Of possible interest, make shows this
/home/pi/esp32/nodemcu-firmware-esp32-241010a/components/modules/u8g2.c:617:12: warning: 'ldisplay_i2c' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
  617 | static int ldisplay_i2c( lua_State *L, display_setup_fn_t setup_fn )

Expecting something like this (from esp8266, but chilipeppr esp32 static firmware would look similar and does work fine for this example)
for k,v in pairs(u8g2) do print(k,v) end
ssd1306_i2c_128x64_noname   function: 0x4024c0b8
uc1601_i2c_128x32   function: 0x4024c09c
ssd1306_i2c_128x32_univision    function: 0x4024c080
ssd1305_i2c_128x32_noname   function: 0x4024c064
ssd1306_128x64_noname   function: 0x4024c0f8
font_6x10_tf    lightfunction: 0x4027e800
font_unifont_t_symbols  lightfunction: 0x4027c518
DRAW_UPPER_RIGHT    1
DRAW_UPPER_LEFT 2
DRAW_LOWER_RIGHT    8
DRAW_LOWER_LEFT 4
DRAW_ALL    15
R0  lightfunction: 0x4027f014
R1  lightfunction: 0x4027f008
R2  lightfunction: 0x4027effc
R3  lightfunction: 0x4027eff0
MIRROR  lightfunction: 0x4027efe4

With esp32 builds, I get this (missing display drivers)
for k,v in pairs(u8g2) do print(k,v) end
font_6x10_tf    userdata: 0x3f40a51e
font_unifont_t_symbols  userdata: 0x3f408236
font_chikita_tf userdata: 0x3f407ae5
DRAW_UPPER_RIGHT    1
DRAW_UPPER_LEFT 2
DRAW_LOWER_RIGHT    8
DRAW_LOWER_LEFT 4
DRAW_ALL    15
R0  userdata: 0x3f40ad30
R1  userdata: 0x3f40ad24
R2  userdata: 0x3f40ad18
R3  userdata: 0x3f40ad0c
MIRROR  userdata: 0x3f40ad00

Searching the make listing shows things that may be of interest.
Including the following modules: FILE;GPIO;HTTP;I2C;NET;NODE;OW;PIPE;TMR;U8G2;UART;WIFI
awk: line 2: function strtonum never defined

and these repeat for RMT, sigma-delta, adc, dac, i2c
/home/pi/esp32/nodemcu-firmware-esp32-241010a/sdk/esp32-esp-idf/components/driver/deprecated/driver/i2s.h:27:2: warning: #warning "This set of I2S APIs has been deprecated, please include 'driver/i2s_std.h', 'driver/i2s_pdm.h' or 'driver/i2s_tdm.h' instead. if you want to keep using the old APIs and ignore this warning, you can enable 'Suppress leagcy driver deprecated warning' option under 'I2S Configuration' menu in Kconfig" [-Wcpp]
   27 | #warning "This set of I2S APIs has been deprecated, \

I have tried builds with i2c and spi or i2c drivers alone
Snippets from make menuconfig follow
[*] U8G2 module
        Displays  --->
        Fonts  --->

[*] I2C  --->
[ ] SPI  ----

[*] ssd1306_i2c_128x32_univision
[*] ssd1306_i2c_128x64_noname

(font_6x10_tf,font_unifont_t_symbols,font_chikita_tf) Font list

Nodemcu Boot Header
NodeMCU ESP32 build 2024-11-07 03:38 powered by Lua 5.3.5 [5.3-int32-singlefp] on IDF v5.1.3
cannot open init.lua: No such file or directory
> =node.heap()
209168

Build Config
for k,v in pairs(node.info("build_config")) do print (k,v) end
number_type float
ssl true
esp_console uart
lfs_size    262144
modules file,gpio,http,i2c,net,node,ow,pipe,tmr,u8g2,uart,wifi

Also sdkconfig deleted before the make menuconfig.
Digging back through my notes, another possible clue is that during firmware build setup, I modified components/modules/node.c by replacing BUILDINFO_LFS_SIZE with 0 due to the following error during make (later changing to 256K)
/home/pi/esp32/nodemcu-firmware-esp32-241010a/components/modules/node.c: In function 'node_info':
/home/pi/esp32/nodemcu-firmware-esp32-241010a/components/modules/node.c:475:45: error: expected expression before ',' token
  475 |       add_int_field(L,    BUILDINFO_LFS_SIZE,   "lfs_size");
...
make failed with exit code 2, output of the command is in the /home/pi/esp32/nodemcu-firmware-esp32-241010a/build/log/idf_py_stderr_output_7451 and /home/pi/esp                                       32/nodemcu-firmware-esp32-241010a/build/log/idf_py_stdout_output_7451
make[1]: *** [Makefile:18: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/esp32/nodemcu-firmware-esp32-241010a'
make: *** [Makefile:10: all] Error 2



I modified components/modules/node.c by replacing BUILDINFO_LFS_SIZE with 0 due to the following error during make (later changing to 256K)

To calculate BUILDINFO_LFS_SIZE, awk "{print strtonum( $1 )}" is currently used.
The strtonum() function is a gawk extension. But the gawk package is not included by default in Debian stable.
You should either install the gawk package or apply PR#3675.
EDIT.
After installing gawk you need to perform make clean
